# Peltier heating/cooling of small surface area

Tags: thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

I am looking at peltier heaters/coolers, and all of them are thin wafers like the one pictured below.

[image: Peltier device]

This works fine for some things (ie. a microchip or a beer coaster) but not for others (ie. anything elongated). Assume, for the sake of argument, that I wish to heat a screwdriver to melt the ice off of frozen screws while I unscrew them. I want to put a peltier device inside of the handle of the screwdriver (as this is the most practical place to conceal it). The problem is that the only point of contact will be with the roughly 0.5cm diameter of the 'bit'. So my question now becomes whether I should somehow use a thermal conductor to connect the peltier device to the screw bit (if so, how inefficient is this), or whether to use a multi level peltier device (in an attempt to elongate the design). Alternatively, is there another solution I have not thought of?

I have included a crude drawing to further clarify my question. Also, ignore for the moment that there is no heat sink in this design.

**Option 1: Using a thermal conductor**
[image]

**Option 2: Using a multi-level peltier device**
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure of the right answer to what you're doing, but certainly putting the entire device inside a thermal insulator with only one side thermally connected to something, isn't going to accomplish anything but convert electricity to waste heat (I^2R) and warm the inside of the insulating container.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to heat the bit to help melt off ice from the screw and do not care about cooling the bit, then the Peltier device, which is a heat pump, is unnecessarily complicated and delicate. The most efficient way to heat something is through a resistive load (i.e. like in a toaster).

There are a number options for making the heater, but a 100 Ohm, 1 Watt resistor hooked up to a 9 V battery will generate V^2/R = 0.8 Watts of heat. Heat shrink the resistor to electrically insulate it and then heat shrink that to the end of the bit to transfer the heat.  A 9 V battery provides about 300 mA hours, so the battery will last about 18 minutes.  With all the heat shrink, there is a chance that the resistor will overheat, so you might need to play around with the resistance, resistor wattage, and connection to the bit.

You can also wrap some very fine gauge magnet wire around the bit a few dozen times and epoxy it in place (or get a coil for a reed relay from digikey). This would require a lower voltage, high current source to heat it though. WARNING: Be careful when disconnecting a power supply from a high inductance coil as you can generate a large voltage during the disconnect if current is flowing (personal experience getting badly shocked). If you do use a reed relay coil, I can describe how to protect against this voltage spike.

Comment: I actually want to freeze something, but I chose the heat example as I couldn't come up with any other example.

Answer (score 1):

A Peltier module is not what you want. Some of the specs that I've seen require minimum currents of a few amps (≈2A for a small module), so unless you want to lug around even a small sealed Lead-acid battery with attendant wires, I'd think of something else. In fact, an electrical solution may not even be suitable.

However, how about modifying a gas soldering pencil - I presume you've got a workshop and tools. You could replace the soldering bit with a hex screw bit holder and change hex screw bits as required. It's self-contained, light and easily fits in your toolbox. Not sure how the pencil assembly will react to screw torques, though.

An even simpler alternative is to use a gas pencil torch and just melt the ice off. However, you may need to exercise a bit of care in not burning any surrounding paint or coating on the enclosure you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a heat pump is inappropriate here, and a bad idea from a engineering standpoint too.  Your heated tip would presumably be used when its cold, so cooling the handle makes little sense.  Since it's cold, there won't be much heat available, so it won't run that effeciently anyway.  Then there is the problem of getting the heat from the handle to the tip, which will be both inefficient and slow.

A much better solution is to heat the shaft near the tip directly.  My first reaction is to use induction heating.  This is assuming the shaft is made of something conductive, like steel.  coil some wire around the shaft as close to the tip as you can manage without getting in the way of the scredriver function.  Drive the wire with a few Amps at a few 100 kHz or maybe close to a MHz (higher is better for the function of the indutive heater, but at high frequencies you will get too much loss in the electronics to be practical).  The wire then becomes the primary of a transformer with the shaft being the secondary.  The circular currents caused in the shaft will heat it due to I<sup>2</sup>R.

You can use the wire as a resistive heater as others have suggested, but that will be a little less efficient.  By running DC current thru the wire, only the wire will heat up, which will eventually heat the shaft, especially if you put thermal insulation around the wire.  With the inductive heating method, much of the heat is created directly inside the shaft in the first place.